# repeat action forever with different durations

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I'm pretty new to Sprite Kit and I'm trying to develop a game where some monsters are moving around forever using this code.

```
    return SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.runBlock({ self.moveMonster(monster) }),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(monster.movementSpeed())
    ])
```

The thing is that I would like the wait duration to vary using the monster speed, which is a function.

This code doesn't achieve what I'm trying to do because the *movementSpeed* function is called only once.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: you'll have to create a new sequence at the end by using another runBlock if you want the wait action to have a different duration for every sequence

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `completionHandler` in `runAction` to add a different `SKAction sequence` each time to change your `wait duration`. For example.

```
func addSKAction(waitDuration : NSTimeInterval)
{
    let moveSprite = SKAction.runBlock({ () -> Void in
        self.moveMonster(monster)
    })

    let waitDuration = SKAction.waitForDuration(waitDuration)

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveSprite,waitDuration])

    spriteNode.runAction(sequence, completion: { () -> Void in

        addSKAction(waitDuration) // Change wait duration each time.

    })
}
```

Change the value of the `waitDuration` variable each time.

If you just want to randomly change `waitDuration`, you can use `SKAction.waitForDuration:withRange:`

```
let moveSprite = SKAction.runBlock({ () -> Void in
    self.moveMonster(monster)
})

let waitDuration = SKAction.waitForDuration(5, withRange: 4)

let sequence = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveSprite,waitDuration]))
```

This will change the `waitDuration` from (5 - range/2) = **3** to (5 + range/2) = **7** randomly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Do you think I should stick with that way or go with the update method. I'm still new and unsure of the best practices.

Comment: it entirely depends on your implementation. both methods are fine actually.

Comment: I kinda liked that solution more but I had some trouble getting the right waitDuration with the new movementSpeeds, it was always unsynchronized, so I went with the other answer

Answer (score 1):

i wouldnt use an action in this case.  when a timer needs to vary I think it makes more sense to use your update method.

declare two properties to your scene

```
var monsterTimer: NSTimerInterval(2)
var monsterInterval: NSTimerInterval(2)
```

in your update method

```
self.monsterTimer -= self.delta

if self.monsterTimer <= 0 {

    self.moveMonster(monster)

    // change the value of monsterInterval if you need to change the delay
    self.monsterTimer = self.monsterInterval  
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure about the delta but I think I get the overall idea. What I could do is use the currentTime of the update method and do  : if (currentTime % SOMEDURATION = 0.0), what do you think?

Comment: not a good idea.   check out my answer here for more info on delta.  it's important to keep track of your current frame's time compared to the last frame time (the delta).  It's useful because you can increment time, create smooth animations, etc.  look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696915/modify-a-repeating-task-sequence-while-running/27697570#27697570